# CDialog not main frame descendant

Tags: mfc, cdialog

Is there a way to make a dialog (CDialog) not descendant of the main frame?

If I don't specify a parent window at creation time the parent window is the main application window. I have tried to use SetOwner and SetParent with a NULL parameter but didn't work.

So is there any way to make a dialog not child of the main window or any other window that ultimately is a child of the main window??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every window is a child of another window. You can't make a window which doesn't have a Parent. Best you can do is to set the parent to `DesktopWindow`. You can get desktop window through [GetDesktopWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633504(VS.85).aspx).